# VMware: any way to take snapshot from client os?

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, vmware-tools

I am running ESXI 6 with a Linux VM.  VMWare tools are installed on the client os.  Is there any way to trigger a snapshot from within the client os?  Without accessing the host directly?

Comment: You mean trigger snapshot creating from Guest OS?

Comment: Yes, exactly,  I want be able to SSH into the Guest OS and somehow tell ESXI to take a snapshot of it.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you could install PowerCLI and use `New-Snapshot [-Name] <String> [-Description <String>] [-Memory] [-Quiesce] [-RunAsync] [-VM] <VirtualMachine[]> [-Server <VIServer[]>] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<CommonParameters>]`. [[1]](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41U1/html/New-Snapshot.html)

From Linux, you'll need to open an SSH client session to the host and use `vim-cmd`:

`vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms` - note `Vmid` of desired VM

`vim-cmd vmsvc/snapshot.create <Vmid> <snapshot name>`

[[2]](http://buildvirtual.net/working-with-snapshots-on-the-esxi-cli/)

Comment: The goal here is to not provide access to the host.

Comment: VMware Tools don't provide this function... If it's a security problem you could build a simple script server (with host access) that starts the snapshot when it's triggered by the guest.